# Finding pathway of a text file

Tags: java, file, filenames

I know there are 2 ways of writing a pathway for a file while reading file in JAVA.

```
//1st way
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\EDSS\\src\\file\\JobList.txt"));
//2nd way
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/file/JobList.txt"));
```

But when I try to convert my format from .java to .exe(Application) with the 1st way in IntelliJ via something called "Build Artifacts", I can open the application smoothly. However, with 2nd way, I cannot open the Application and I found out that it is because of the pathway. And 1st way only allow me to run the Application in my computer only. If I copy the file to my friend's laptop with different username, for example ("C:\Users\Bernard..."), the application cannot work too and I have to manually modify the pathway in the codes to run the Application.
Is there any way to search for a pathway accurately without manually type the full length out  and at the same time, the Application (.exe) can work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run into the problems with absolute and relative paths.

Your first option is an absolute path. which means you will always grab the file in a particular location on the computer but if that location does not exist you can't find it

Your second option uses relative path which will look for a file based on the starting location of your program so an exe might start from a different location then the command line you build java from.

The solution is to use relative paths and to make sure the Joblist.txt file is always in one location relative to your run location.

If you want to know where the starting path of your program is you can run the following code:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())
```

Comment: I tried to use relative path with Joblist.txt already in the correct location. But when I clicked the .exe, the window showed up very quickly, like 0.01s,and close.. But if I use absolute path, the window appeared and worked fine....

Comment: probably as the exe starts the relative path from an different starting point. You can find tat point with: System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath()) /or write it to your log or something. then you can start figuring out why relative path does not work.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution.   .exe uses a different directory.